# Is there a way to create non-ingestion time based partition tables for big query with the java driver?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I've been looking around, and even with the latest big query java driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.81.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It only seems to give the option of partitioning based on load/ingestion time.

```
TimePartitioning.of(Type.DAY);
```

Is there another option or class that I should be using to partition based on specific DATE or TIMESTAMP columns? or is this just not supported in the java driver?

Comment: Did you try executing a `CREATE TABLE` statement? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_partitioned_table

Comment: I know that I can do it via the UI, but was hoping it was available within java so we could integrate it with our existing workflows.  That said, using a create table statement via the bigquery API might work as a handy workaround. will have to dig in to it. :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems not possible with [Java](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/0.100.0-alpha/com/google/cloud/bigquery/TimePartitioning.Type.html) but possible with [Python and Go](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_an_empty_partitioned_table_with_a_schema_definition) client libraries, DDL statement, UI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the client documentation [it is supported](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/TimePartitioning.Builder.html#setField-java.lang.String-).

Here is an example:

```java
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

String my_field = "my_field";
Schema schema = Schema.of(Field.of(my_field, LegacySQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP));

// Here is where we set the field we want to be used for the partition
TimePartitioning timePartitioning = TimePartitioning.newBuilder(TimePartitioning.Type.DAY)
                                                      .setField(my_field)
                                                      .build();

TableDefinition tableDef = StandardTableDefinition.newBuilder()
                                          .setSchema(schema)
                                          .setTimePartitioning(timePartitioning)
                                          .build();

TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(TableId.of("dataset", "table"), tableDef).build();

Table table = bigquery.create(tableInfo);
```